# How many intersection points can two graphs have?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $F$ and $G$ be copies of the complete equipartite graph with each partition of size $v$. That is, $F,G:= K_{v,v,\dots ,v}$. Prove that if $F$ and $G$ intersect in at more than $v$ vertices, then they MUST share a common edge.

I am having some trouble proving this. It seems quite intuitive that the answer is $v$ but hard to rigorize. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $F$ and $G$ are *subgraphs* of the complete equipartite graph?

Comment: No, F and G are both separate copies of the complete equipartite graph $K_{v,\dots v}$. I am asking what is the maximum number of vertices they can intersect at without having a common edge. I conjecture the answer is $v$. I will edit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ and $G$ be complete equipartite graphs. If $F$ and $G$ have two common vertices $x$ and $y$ that belong to different partite sets, then there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ since the graph is *complete* equipartite.

Suppose $F$ and $G$ have more than $v$ common vertices. Since the size of a partite set is $v$, the pigeonhole principle implies that $F$ and $G$ share two common vertices belonging to different partite sets. The preceding paragraph allows us to conclude that $F$ and $G$ share an edge.